# Classification of links with unknot components

Tags: knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology, knot-invariants

#### Question

I am interested in the links in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with trivial components. More precisely, I'd like to know if the classification of links with finitely many components, which are all unknots have been done.

#### Background

With only one component, the problem is trivial. With two components, I believe it should be classified by how many times they "wrap together" (linking number?). With **three components, however**, I fail to be confident to say I can classify all of them. I hope the classification can be done by drawing graphs.

#### Variants

It would also be nice to know of the variants:

1. links -> oriented links
2. unrestricted linking number -> each linking number is $\pm 1$.

Comment: I suggest you pick up a textbook on knots and links, say, Rolfsen, and start reading. This will provide you with clear definitions and clear many misconceptions.

Comment: It seems to me that the way to think about this is by looking at the braid groups. A braid induces a permutation on its strands, and the links you're interested in are exactly those which, considered as elements of a braid group, induce the identity permutation.

Comment: @MoisheKohan is my definition/question not clear?

Comment: I think the goal is a little loftier than you realize here and probably what @MoisheKohan is getting at.  We don't have a good way to even look at all diagrams of the unknot.  If we add trivial component and link the two, you can get very nontrivial things very quickly.  But try it out and see what you come up with.  We have been surprised before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the oldest examples of nontrivial links with zero linking number is the [Whitehead Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_link).

[image: Whitehead Link]

There are many other examples.

If your wish is to classify, say, 2-component, links where each component is an unknot, by some simple numerical invariant (like the linking number), then there is no such classification. (One can even make this statement precise once you have defined what "simple" is.) There is a classification, of sorts, which works for general links. It is given by [Thurston's Hyperbolization Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolization_theorem). For instance, for 2-component links where both components are unknots, the classification says that either the link complement is **hyperbolic** or it is a torus link (the Hopf link is a simple example), or it is the result of a "satellite construction" (the complement contains an "essential torus"). This classification is quite useful but I am pretty sure, this is not what you asked for. As I said in my comments, if you are interested in knots and links, pick up a book (say, "Knots and Links" by Dale Rolfsen -- it is a bit dated but still covers all the basics) and start reading.

Comment: This is mind-blowing. And you were right, I'm way too naive to ask any meaningful question. I hope to learn this towards some physics. Do you think Kauffman's Knots and Physics is also a good book to start with?

Comment: @Student: It is ok, but I would supplement with Rolfsen's book or "Knot Book" by Adams.